# EF Core: How to load data from a table and related tables in Generic Repository

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, repository-pattern

I created a `Generic Repository` that can help me in my projects.

**The problem:**

In these days I work on a project and I want to get data from some related tables *(all data from one table and also load all related data from other tables that I select)*, the repository I was created can't handle this also I don't want to work directly with Entity Framework Core.

**My repository:**

My repository is an open source project, you can see the source code [from here](https://dev.azure.com/MB-Solutions/MBRepoCore).

**What I want exactly:**

My idea is to create a method in my `generic repository`, this method will receive the entity that I want to select data from, and receive an expression that told it to load data from the scent entity and some related tables *(not all related table but some related table that I will send in the expression)*.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: If the repository pattern is getting in the way, don't use it....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is highly dependent on your specific implementation of generic repository, but the following code might help you to get the idea -

```cs
public async Task<TEntity> LoadSingleWithRelatedAsync<TEntity>(TEntity entity, params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] expressionList) where TEntity : EntityBase
{
    if (entity == null)
        return null;

    var query = _DbCtx.Set<TEntity>().AsQueryable();
    foreach (var expression in expressionList)
    {
        query = query.Include(expression);
    }

    return await query.FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == entity.Id);
}
```

where `EntityBase` is -

```cs
public class EntityBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Following is an example of how you would use it -

```cs
// Order has a Customer parent and a list of OrderLine children
var loadedOrder = await _Repo.LoadSingleWithRelatedAsync(order, p => p.Customer, p => p.OrderLines);
```

1. `Order` must be a class derived from `EntityBase`
2. `order` can be `Detached` entity (e.g. received through a method parameter from client side), or an already existing entity fetched from database

**EDIT: 2021.04.01**
If you want a collection instead of a single entity, the method might look like -

```cs
public async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> LoadAllWithRelatedAsync<TEntity>(params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] expressionList) where TEntity : class
{
    var query = _DbCtx.Set<TEntity>().AsQueryable();
    foreach (var expression in expressionList)
    {
        query = query.Include(expression);
    }

    return await query.ToListAsync();
}
```

Here -

1. `TEntity` is not required to have the constraint of being an `EntityBase` type, since we don't have any use of the `Id` property
2. The parameter `entity` is not needed, since we are not looking for a specific entity
3. To identify the type in the calling code, the type parameter must be used when calling the method -

```cs
// Order has a Customer parent and a list of OrderLine children
var orderList = await _Repo.LoadAllWithRelatedAsync<Order>(p => p.Customer, p => p.OrderLines);
```

Comment: Firstly massive thanks for your time and effort, but I'm confused how can I send order in the last using example you provided, I don't know if I should send the `Order` parameter as type or `Order` class object or what ? And massive thanks again bro really I appreciate this for you

Comment: @DEV Please check the `EDIT`.

Comment: Really I appreciate this for your brother, massive thanks for your time and effort, I have just one more question the answer I provided below your answer what are you thinking about it, in other words the solution I provided in below of your answer **it has a performance issue or other problems ??** And massive thanks again bro

Comment: @DEV I've updated the post and the code, please check. There is a issue in the code of your answer - `ToList()` returns a new list with each call, so in `result` you'll the get only the last included related entity. Have you tested the code?

Comment: Please can you update your answer to return a list of records from sent `entity` and also load all related entities, because I need  a  `list` of records at all, also another question if I won't use the `baseEntity` `Id` what I can do ? and realy massive thanks

Comment: @DEV I have mentioned in the code how to return a list - just return `.ToListAsync()` instead of `.FirstOrDefaultAsync()`. As for not using `BaseEntity`, it will depend on how you implemented your repository. I don't use generic repositories, I use generic methods in my `DbContext` and I chose to constraint my `TEntity` to be a `BaseEntity` type.

Comment: Really appreciate this for you brother, massive thanks again for your time and effort