# How to map property of related entity when you have Id of the related entity

Tags: c#, automapper

I have the following entities, view model classes and used AutoMapper to map them. I basically now need to map the ViewModel field `CategoryName` to the `Category` entity's `Name` field.

If you see in the AutoMapper code below, I have tried the following but unable to map `Category` entity's `Name` field. How can I do that?

```cs
CreateMap<Product, ProductDto>()
    .ForMember(x => x.CategoryName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src));
```

Entities -

```cs
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(200)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(200)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel -

```cs
public class ProductDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
}

public class CategoryDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

AutoMapper classes -

```cs
public class CategoryProfile : Profile
{
    public CategoryProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Category, CategoryDto>().ReverseMap();
    }
}

public class ProductProfile : Profile
{
    public ProductProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Product, ProductDto>()
            .ForMember(x => x.CategoryName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src));
    }
}
```

Controller

```
 public ProductsController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IMapper mapper)
        {
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
            _mapper = mapper;
        }

       [HttpGet]
       public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
        {
            var productEntities = await _unitOfWork.Products.GetAll();
            return  Ok( _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ProductDto>>(productEntities));

        }
```

Repository

```
public abstract class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
    {

        protected readonly ProductContext _context;
        public GenericRepository(ProductContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
  
       public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAll()
         {
           
            //return await _context.Set<T>().Include(p => p.).ToListAsync();
            return await _context.Set<T>().ToListAsync();
        }
        
        
          public async Task<T> Get(int id)
        {
            return await _context.Set<T>().FindAsync(id);
        }
        
    }
```

EDIT 1

Generic repository

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> LoadRelatedAsync<T>(T entity, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] expressionList)  where T : class
        {
            if (entity == null)
                return null;

            IQueryable<T> query = _context.Set<T>().AsQueryable();
            foreach (var expression in expressionList)
            {
                query = query.Include(expression);
            }

             return await query.ToListAsync();
        }
```

Comment: There is no relation between your models. How did you configure them? Also, how do you query for `Product` with `Category`?

Answer (score 2):

Even though your question doesn't have any tag for `Entity Framework` or `Entity Framework Core`, the attributes on your model properties clearly indicates these entities are supposed to come from database. Also, the `CategoryId` property in the `Product` model indicates you intend to have a one-to-many relation between `Product` and `Category`. But currently you don't have that relationship.

To achieve your required mapping you'll need to define the following map -

```cs
CreateMap<Product, ProductDto>()
    .ForMember(x => x.CategoryName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Category.Name));
```

But this code will not compile because you don't have any `Category` property in the `Product` entity. So, you have to add the following property in `Product` entity -

```cs
public Category Category { get; set; }
```

This will automatically create a one-to-many relationship between `Product` and `Category`. You can also configure the relationship manually with the following method in your `DbContext` -

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Entity<Product>(e =>
    {
        e.HasOne(p => p.Category)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(p => p.CategoryId);
    });
}
```

Then, you can query `Product` with its related `Category` from the database, and map it to your ViewModel like below -

```cs
var product = context.Products
                .Include(p => p.Category)
                .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == someId);
                
var viewModel = myMapper.Map<ProductDto>(product);
```

Alternatively, you can use `ProjectTo` method of `AutoMapper`, which will generate `SQL` query to do the projection in the database and you don't have to load the entire `Category` entity just to select a single field -

```cs
var viewModel = myMapper.ProjectTo<ProductDto>(context.Products)
                        .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == someId);
```

Comment: `ProjectTo` fits better here.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Yep. I agree. And now that you mentioned, I'll add that too. Thanks.

Comment: I have made the changes you suggested to apply the one to many relationship. I reseeded the database and can see the foreign key set as well. The Category object is null when the GetAll method is invoked and hence the CategoryName is still Null. I presume that is because I am not loading Category while querying the products. I am using repository pattern and unit of work in the my code hence doesn't seem that straightforward. I am not sure how to use the either the include or projectTo in my case. I have updated the post to show my call to repository

Comment: I have tried adding this to the product repository and seems to work but does not look clean as it is hard coded

Comment: public async Task<IEnumerable<Product>> GetAll()
        {

            return await _context.Set<Product>().Include("Category").ToListAsync();
            //return await _context.Set<T>().ToListAsync();
        }

Comment: Is there a better way of doing this ?

Comment: @Tom You have to add a new method in your repository. This answer might help - https://stackoverflow.com/a/66683751/446519. The implementation in the answer returns a `TEntity`, but you can return `query.ToListAsync()` to get a list, and then apply `.Map()` on it. Or, you can return just the `query` to get an `IQueryable<TEntity>`, and then apply `.ProjectTo()` on it. If the linked answer helps in any way, you can upvote it  ;)

Comment: @atiyar : Thanks for the link. I have created the method in my generic repository. How do I use it in my controller :) . I already have the controller code in my post. It would be of great help

Comment: @Tom You don't need the `entity` parameter if you want to return a list. Also, you must use the type parameter when calling the method. I've added an `EDIT` to the linked answer to clarify. Basically, you'll need something like `var productList = await _unitOfWork.Products.LoadRelatedAsync<Product>(p => p.Category);`

Answer (score 0):

As you need to map the `ProductDto ViewModel's` field `CategoryName` to the `Category Entity's` field `Name` or vice versa. So, you can alter your CreateMap code like this:

```
    CreateMap<ProductDto, Category>().ForMember(destination => destination.Name,
              options => options.MapFrom(source => source.CategoryName));
```

OR

```
    CreateMap<Category, ProductDto>().ForMember(destination => destination.CategoryName,
              options => options.MapFrom(source => source.Name));
```

Hope that it might help you!

Comment: `ReverseMap` will automatically reverse the `MapFrom` for you.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. Why would you create a map between `ProductDto` and `Category?!

Comment: @atiyar, I actually followed what is asked in the question by the poster :) Besides, you may notice that given `viewmodel` and `entity` allows to do that :)

Comment: please do let me know if my entity and view model are incorrect. I created a property called CategoryName in the ViewModel as i felt CategoryId does not make any sense. But now the doubt that i have is when the client posts the json object , it would contain the categoryId and not CategoryName. So I am now confused with the what should my viewmodel contain ?

Comment: @SalahuddinAhmed And how exactly do you intend to use that map you defined? You'll get the Id, Name and Description of a `Category` in a `ProductDto`, and still `Price` property will be missing.

Comment: @atiyar, I assumed that `vewmodel` and `entity` were in correct state and thus just showed how the `CreateMap` should be implemented for the particular mapping in this case :)